# tmux/zsh/mac terminal inserts extra spaces in small pane

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm not sure where the problem with this is, because I've had the same problem with iTerm2 and its pane management system on bash.

Sometimes, when I have a pane whose width is smaller than the full window, something will get "decalibrated" and all of the shell output will have extra spaces in front of it.

I would post an example, but apparently I need 10 reputation to do that.

Essentially, it's just that there are extra spaces at the front of each line, so the output is chaotic. Normally, the beginning of each line should go all the way on the left, but here they seem to be starting below where the last line ended, making it look quite chaotic.

Clearly there's something not right here. I think it usually happens when I quit a vim session, and often if my vim session errors out for some reason. Meanwhile, full screen programs (like vim) don't have this problem. Additionally, my prompt and inputs are pretty much entirely correct. It seems to only be output.

Any ideas/solutions?

edit: this might not only be with panes: when I zoom in on the problematic pane, the problem still exists.

Comment: My only thought is that it looks like carriage returns (`\r`) aren't in the result. I don't always have this issue, though.

Comment: I'd say you probably screwed up somehow. Always try `stty sane` first. "If my vim session errors out for some reason" — that one strengthens my hypothesis.

Comment: Well, the only reason I could imagine my vim erroring out randomly (which it does from time to time unfortunately) is because of something Janus does. When it errors out, it's usually after I quit with `:wq`.